# Can I combine the history of two files in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

I need to combine the functionality of two classes into one, but I am wondering can I combine their change history as well?

Both classes contains lots of previous changes, so I want to keep their change history in one place for reference. I can make a comment in the combined class, but in an IDE, it's not very easy to get the history of a deleted file.

Comment: This would go against detailing the history of the class merge. Each file would have its individual history before the merge, and from the merge onwards the new file would have its own history. I can't really see the use case for wanting to merge history that is completely disconnected.

Comment: I am reusing one of the class files, so the history of that will be directly available in the IDE. However, you'll have to type commands to see the history of the file that is deleted, which is quite inconvenient. I also lose information like change annotations in the side-bar for code from the deleted class.

Comment: I have a similar use case: two small, related files that really should be a single file (but for some reason were split apart long ago, before version control). Pulling the two together makes sense, but being able to see the history of both is important.

Comment: A use case where this is valuable is if a file was deleted / re-added rather than being renamed in Hg. In that case, later merges from branches where the original file was modified will not merge those changes into the re-added file. But if you merge their history then this should be possible.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To do this, you need to record the file merging as a merge changeset.

Say changeset 0 is your current head with files A and B which you want to merge into file C. To do this, rename your file A to C and commit as changeset 1, then update back to changeset 0, rename file B to C and commit this as changeset 2. Next, you merge these two changesets, combining their content and removing the remaining files A and B. This causes the file history of C to be registered as descending from both A and B. Finally you can rename file C back to A.

The resulting tree looks as follows:

```
0 [A, B] --- 1 [A, C] \
          \            \
           \ 2 [C, B] --- 3 [C] --- 4 [A]
```

Example command line flow:

```
$ hg init
$ echo a > a
$ echo b > b
$ hg add a b
$ hg commit -m "add files a and b"
$ hg mv a c
$ hg commit -m "rename a to c"
$ hg update 0
1 files updated, 0 files merged, 1 files removed, 0 files unresolved
$ hg mv b c
$ hg commit -m "rename b to c"
created new head
$ hg merge
merging c
warning: conflicts during merge.
merging c incomplete! (edit conflicts, then use 'hg resolve --mark')
0 files updated, 0 files merged, 1 files removed, 1 files unresolved
use 'hg resolve' to retry unresolved file merges or 'hg update -C .' to abandon
$ ls
c      c.orig
$ cat c
<<<<<<< local
b
=======
a
>>>>>>> other
$ echo ab > c
$ hg resolve --mark c
$ hg commit -m "merge a and b into c"
$ hg mv c a
$ hg commit -m "rename c back to a"
```

And if you now type `hg log -f a` you will notice that the history of both files is shown.